# C# Discord Bot Coding: Creating a command that spams messages then stops with another command

Tags: c#, discord

I just need a working line of code that spams a message every five seconds then stops after another command is entered. Like for an example, if a user enters "~raid" then the bot will spam "RAID RAID" every five seconds and stops when the user does "~stop". If anyone could help that'd be awesome.

Here is what I got so far:
    class MyBot
    {
        DiscordClient discord;
        CommandService commands;

```
    public MyBot()
    {
        discord = new DiscordClient(x =>
        {
            x.LogLevel = LogSeverity.Info;
            x.LogHandler = Log;
        });

        discord.UsingCommands(x =>
        {
            x.PrefixChar = '~';
            x.AllowMentionPrefix = true;
        });

        commands = discord.GetService<CommandService>();

        commands.CreateCommand("checked")
            .Do(async (e) =>
            {

        commands.CreateCommand("weewoo")
            .Do(async (e) =>
            {
                await e.Channel.SendMessage("**WEE WOO**");
            });

        discord.ExecuteAndWait(async () =>
        {
            await discord.Connect("discordkeyhere", TokenType.Bot);
        });
    }

    public void Log(object sender, LogMessageEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The problem is implementing the stop command?

Comment: Yea and how to make it so the message repeats itself every 5 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small example how you could do it.
In this case, you can Start and Stop your bot from outside using the methods Start and Stop.

```
class MyBot
{
    public MyBot()
    {
    }

    CancellationTokenSource cts;

    public void Start()
    {
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task t = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (!cts.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("RAID RAID");
                Task.Delay(5000).Wait();
            }
        }, cts.Token);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        cts?.Cancel();
    }
}
```

Here is the code to test the MyBot class

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var b = new MyBot();

            while (true)
            {
                var input = Console.ReadLine();
                if (input.Equals("~raid", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    b.Start();
                else if (input.Equals("~stop", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    b.Stop();
                else if (input.Equals("exit", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    break;
                Task.Delay(1000);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: And this would work with Discord? If it does, could you do work it in with the code? I dont wanna mess it up xD

Comment: I'm using visual studio btw

Comment: The code is just an example. You have to adjust the code to get it working in your specific application. You just have to get the commands from the user and react to them. Hope that helps.

Comment: @user8328934 luckily the discord API (which you'll have to use) has documentation: https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/reference